# Entity Framework: Dynamic Columns & Dynamic Object Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Usually when working with entity framework, I use something on the lines of;

```
List<students> students = db.Students.ToList();
```

In my case; I am working with a SQL Server database which I am not allowed to change anything out of it. (this includes creating my own SPs and Functions)

Within this database, there is a view that holds the stock quantities of products for each shop branch in the format of branch_1_stock, branch_2_stock ... branch_x_stock. Whenever user creates another branch (which is created in the branches table), the said view updates itself and now includes another column e.g. branch_3_stock where the number is the index number of the branch record in the branches table.

So, with column names being dynamically created by the database itself which I have no control over, how would I go and get the stock quantity of a product for each branch or the list of all products with stock quantities?

- I have tried creating an ExpandoObject but had problems applying it to my logic
- I have tried executing sql command string against the database but it came with its own downfalls e.g. creating a seperate connection string, also I failed to cast the results to an object of some sort.

All I can think of is to iterate through the branches table, get the index and name of each branch, then use plain sql string build within a loop so that I can have the column names as "branch_" + i + "_stock" to query the databse. But this would need a object with dynamic properties? Any way to have a strongly typed solution to this?

If experienced programmers see this, what would be the correct way of overcoming problems as this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not query the tables the view is based off of instead?

Comment: I can, but then how do I know how many columns of branches do I have? If I knew, I would have cast it to an object with the same number of branch properties within the view. But there might be another branch inserted tomorrow to the table

Comment: It sounds like the view is doing a pivot.  You should be able to get the data you want un-pivotted.  Then you can pivot it in memory.  It really depends on what the table looks like and how you want to use the data.

Comment: The view columns are: ProductID, ProductName, branch_1_stock, branch_2_stock, branch_3_stock .... branch_x_stock.. Eventually what I am trying to achieve is display a table of a single or all the products with their relative stock quantities by joining the number part of the branch_x_stock with the actual branches table. So, The table I want to achieve would be like Product Name | LondonBranchStock | BarcelonaBranchStock ...

Comment: Isnt the columns equal to the number of the branches available on the branch table ? If yes you know upon runtime the number of the branch properties. From there you can go ahead and use a key value pair of (BranchName,Stock Value)

Comment: IMHO, sounds like old school ADO.Net is  "better" way of dealing with it (I think you've alluded to it)